# Java - MySQL | double and decimal point

Tags: java, mysql, double

I have a problem with my double.
It only shows 1 digit after the comma instead of putting everything in my mysql table:

```
public static double getFactionDtr(int id) throws SQLException{
    double dtr = 1;
    PreparedStatement queryStatement = FactionDatabase.createStatement("SELECT dtr FROM factionmanagement WHERE id = ?");
    queryStatement.setInt(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = queryStatement.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next()) {
        return Double.valueOf(dtr);
    }
    dtr = rs.getInt("dtr");
    queryStatement.close();
    return Double.valueOf(dtr);
}
```

The result is `0.0` and in my mysql table `0.001`

Comment: Side note: why are you using `Double.valueOf` all the time? It's useless in this scenario, `dtr` already is a `double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dtr = rs.getInt("dtr");
```

Here, you get an **integer** value from your result set which cannot contain a fractional part.

Replace it with

```
dtr = rs.getDouble("dtr");
```

Also, your final line does some strange thing: it wraps `double` with `Double` and then (using unboxinb) converts `Double` back to `double`:

```
return Double.valueOf(dtr);
```

Just return `dtr`:

```
return dtr;
```

Comment: Oh yes, i haven't see .. Thanks <3